# React Native - How to run on iOS device from xcode with DEV = FALSE

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native

When running my react native app on the connected iPhone I see that the app is being run with DEV=TRUE:
[image]

I am running the app by opening the xcode project file, and pressing the play button.

How can I do the same but make it run with DEV = false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hold the option key when you hit run in xcode and change the drop down from debug to release.

Answer (score 1):

On the react [website](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/running-on-device-ios.html) you can find how to do this

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle
```

Comment: I did this. And indeed the bundle file is created, but this dose not change things. When I press play in xcode, I still get dev=true.